# Change the CSS of the first image in a Google Drive document

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-drive-api

I have a problem.. I have a site where every page is managed in gdrive. I want to change the css of only the firts image of one page. I can't use :first-child etc because the html is full of "p > span > img"
Writing p > span > img:first-child {css} for example, the page take every image not only the first..
Someone could help me?

Sorry for my bad english and thanks

The image isn't in the firts p so i can't use $('p > span > img').first().css('prop':'value');

And if I use this every img inside a p will take this attribute

Answer (score 0):

So you want the first image on the entire page?

```
$('img').first().css('prop':'value');
```

or possibly:

```
$('p > span > img').first().css('prop':'value');
```

http://api.jquery.com/first

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use javascript, try the answer above. For a straight CSS solution, try img:nth-of-type(1).